# Where can I find the changelog for Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am using Ubuntu on my Nexus phone and I would like to know where I can find updates to what is changing on the device so I can follow along with development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu Touch generally follows a separate release schedule than the standard Ubuntu desktop and therefore information about its releases are published separately. Whenever a new OTA update is released an announcement e-mail is sent to the Ubuntu Phone mailing-list with changes information and LP milestone links.

I will try to formalise the release notes format so that everything is in one place - once that happens I will update this response. In the meantime, here's how things look like right now:

The mailing list archives:

- https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/date.html

The current place for all changelogs/commitlogs for stable OTAs:

- http://people.canonical.com/~lzemczak/landing-team/ota/

Per-image commitlogs for the -proposed channels (both stable and devel):

- Devel (numbers based on mako images): http://people.canonical.com/~lzemczak/landing-team/ubuntu/vivid/
- Stable (numbers based on krillin images): http://people.canonical.com/~lzemczak/landing-team/ubuntu-rtm/

Answer (score 4):

http://people.canonical.com/~j-lallement/touch/changes has them now.

There's also some detail at the linked pages http://people.canonical.com/~ogra/touch-image-stats/

Answer (score 0):

You can find the changelog, release notes and all updates pertaining the Ubuntu touch project on this [**Ubuntu Touch Wiki Page**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes)

Comment: That page has release notes and the like, but no build-by-build changelog.

Comment: http://people.canonical.com/~j-lallement/touch/changes/ has them now.

Comment: @popey Can you please post this as your own answer so I can award you the bounty? Thanks!