# Changelog of bq-Channel for Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, launchpad, changelog

I'm running Ubuntu Touch at the channel 'ubuntu-touch/rc-proposed/bq-aquaris.en'.

My current version is r272.

I would really like to know what had been changed since version r271.
I already searched on launchpad, but I cannot find the related content.

Where can I find out the change log (or commit log)?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/298728/where-can-i-find-the-changelog-for-ubuntu-touch ? seems to point to http://people.canonical.com/~j-lallement/touch/changes/ though that is based on -date- and http://people.canonical.com/~lzemczak/landing-team/ota/